# Polymer elements: to nest or not to nest?

Tags: polymer

We're developing a data visualization library using Polymer, and I must say I'm impressed with what Polymer lets you do. We do have a question, though...

First: here's an example snippet of code showing a data visualization:

```
<template is="auto-binding">
    <our-loaddata url="data/data.csv" data="{{data}}"></our-loaddata>
    <our-scatterplot data="{{data}}"></our-scatterplot>
    <our-barchart data="{{data}}" dimension="weight"></our-barchart>
    <our-histogram data="{{data}}" dimension="weight" binSize=10></our-histogram>
</template>
```

The `our-loaddata` loads the dataset from a file `data/data.csv`, performs some transformations (e.g. converting strings to numbers, calculating distributions, ...) and makes it available through `{{data}}` to the `our-scatterplot`, `our-barchart` and `our-histogram`. However, I'm not completely satisfied with the setup. Conceptually, the `our-loaddata` is different from the other three, *and* should precede them. As an alternative, we have also tried the following (renaming `loaddata` to `app` and nesting all visuals within the app):

```
<template is="auto-binding">
    <our-app url="data/data.csv" data="{{data}}">
        <our-scatterplot data="{{data}}"></our-scatterplot>
        <our-barchart data="{{data}}" dimension="weight"></our-barchart>
        <our-histogram data="{{data}}" dimension="weight" binSize=10></our-histogram>
    </our-app>
</template>
```

Although this also works, we noticed that it doesn't matter if we close the `</our-app>` element before or after all the visual elements.

What would be the most canonical way to handle this in Polymer? What is the difference between the approaches that I showed here?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the conditional template to check if data is present and then send the other elements to the dom if true or show a loader if false. (careful getting to used to this i don't think it is currently in 0.8. sad IMO i <3 it)

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <our-loaddata url="data/data.csv" data="{{data}}"></our-loaddata>
  <template if="{{data}}">
    <our-scatterplot data="{{data}}"></our-scatterplot>
    <our-barchart data="{{data}}" dimension="weight"></our-barchart>
    <our-histogram data="{{data}}" dimension="weight" binSize=10></our-histogram>
  </template>
  <template if="{{!data}}">
    <pretty-loadingscreen></pretty-loadingscreen>
  </template>
</template>
```

the would give you seperation of elements you were looking for.